# Executing oracle stored procedure using c# throws error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error\nORA-06512

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am using the following stored procedure in oracle

```
PROCEDURE proc_test (
    product_id                  IN Product_map.product_id%type,
    external_product_id                   IN Product_map.ex_product_id%type,
    product_seller               OUT VARCHAR2,
    product_name                 OUT VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
     SELECT  seller, product_name
     INTO    product_seller, name
     FROM    product_map
     WHERE   product_id = product_id
     AND     ex_product_id = external_product_id;

END;
```

Datatypes

```
product_id        VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)
ex_product_id     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
product_seller    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
product_name      VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
```

C# code to execute stored proc and return value

```
using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=ORCL; User ID=scott; Password=tiger"))
{
    OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
    objCmd.Connection = objConn;
    objCmd.CommandText = "proc_test";
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdBuilder.Parameters.Add("product_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "a123";
    cmdBuilder.Parameters.Add("external_product_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "xyz123";
    cmdBuilder.Parameters.Add("product_seller", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdBuilder.Parameters.Add("product_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    try
    {
        objConn.Open();
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Product name is is {objCmd.Parameters["product_name"].Value}");  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       System.Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}",ex.ToString());
    }
    objConn.Close();
}
```

I get the following error -

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error\nORA-06512.

Comment: Should your stored procedure not be `SELECT  seller, product_name
                            INTO    product_seller, product_name`? You are assigning a value to an undeclared value

Comment: specify size for varchar params

Comment: try to set the size of `varchar2` parameters: `cmdBuilder.Parameters["product_id"].Size = 300;`

Comment: When you inspect the exception in the debugger, do you see any line numbers or other info that helps pinpoint the issue (maybe in an InnerException)?